# Check constraint is not created at the time of table creation

Tags: mysql, constraints, mysql-workbench

I created a table using the following query. I created a check constraint to make sure that the user inserts either the phone number or the fax number.

```
Create table Suppliers
(SupplierId int(10) not null auto_increment primary key,
CompanyName varchar(100) not null,
ContactName varchar(50) null,
ContactTitle varchar(50) null,
Address varchar(100) not null,
City varchar(50) not null,
Region varchar(50) not null,
PostalCode char(10) not null,
Country varchar(50) not null,
Phone varchar(15) null,
Fax varchar(15) null,
HomePage varchar(150) null,
constraint c_phone_fax check(Phone is not null or fax is not null)
);
```

But however, the check constraint is not created. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: Alter Table tablename Drop Constraint constraintname

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson I tried using the same query like I mentioned in the question. I just don't understand why it is throwing me a syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure the constraint is created in the first place? It isn't when I run the create table code.

Comment: @P.Salmon I tried show create table suppliers. The resulting query doesn't show the constraint that I had entered into the table. Does this mean it wasn't created? I am new to MySQL, I'm more comfortable using MS-SQL but my class requires me to use MYSQL so life sucks.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html -  'The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines'. I must admit that I didn't know they were ignored completely. You can interrogate information_schema.table_constraints at any time to see what constraints are in place for example 
select * from information_schema.table_constraints where table_schema = 'sandbox' and table_name = 'suppliers'

Comment: Er no.. See previous comment and documentation. And you edited the question to something completely different - that's a no no you should have created a new question

Answer (score 0):

Capitalize the 's' of the table name in your command:

```
alter table Suppliers drop constraint c_phone_fax
```

Read more on MySQL's [identifier case sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

Comment: The query should work fine, but then for some reason, the check constraint is not created at all. So I changed the question to address the same. Thank you for the response though. But focusing on the case-sensitivity, SQL is not a case-sensitive language I believe.